# Tetrahedron in $\mathbb R^5$.

Tags: reference-request, notation

Let $\textbf{x}=(x,y,z)$ and $\mathcal S_3=\left\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb R^3|\, x+2y+3z\leq1\, , \, x\geq0\, , \, y\geq 0\, , \, z\geq0 \right\}$. The set $\mathcal S$ forms a tetrahedron in $\mathbb R^3$.

Let us now consider $\mathcal S_4$ or $\mathcal S_5$. For example: 
$$\mathcal S_5=\left\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb R^5|\, x+2y+3z+4w+5u\leq1\, , \, x\geq0\, , \, y\geq 0\, , \, z\geq0\, , \, w\geq0\, , \, u\geq0 \right\}\, ,$$
where $\textbf{x}=(x,y,z,w,u)$.

It should be a tetrahedron in $\mathbb R^5$. But what is its precise definition? A "hyper-tetrahedron"? A "generalized tetrahedron"? For example, $x+2y+3z+4w+5u$ is called "hyper plane" in $\mathbb R^5$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general term is *simplex*, or $n $-simplex if you want to mention the dimension.   A triangle is a $2$-simplex in this context.

Note that the $n$-simplex has $n+1$ vertices, and in fact is the unique convex set generated by those "corners", no $k+1$ of which are in a common $k-1$ dimensional affine hyperplane.